# get the last name of authors joined by `and` in php

Tags: php, preg-match

Suppose I have string of authors:

```
$str1="Evans, C. J. and Ebin, Kupper and Nirenberg, Jhon France";
$str2="Evans, C. J.";
```

How can get their <del>first</del> last name by `preg_match()`?

The output should be, respectively:

```
EvansEbinNirenberg
Evans
```

Thanks!

Comment: That’s actually their last names.

Comment: @Gumbo Thanks, I will fix this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

`/([A-Z])\w+(?=,)/g`

Demo: http://regexr.com/3a9kf

PHP Code:

```
$str1="Evans, C. J. and Ebin, Kupper and Nirenberg, Jhon France";
$str2="Evans, C. J.";

preg_match_all('/([A-Z])\w+(?=,)/',$str1,$matches);
echo implode('',$matches[0])."\n";

preg_match_all('/([A-Z])\w+(?=,)/',$str2,$matches);
echo implode('',$matches[0]);
```

Comment: Seems work on the demo, but what should I replace `/g` in php?

Comment: I see, `preg_match_all`

Comment: Another last question, why `[A-Z]` matchs the lower latter also? and without add `/i`

Comment: I see, maybe `/\b\w+\b(?=,)/` is better to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `explode()`

```
$str1="Evans, C. J. and Ebin, Kupper and Nirenberg, Jhon France";
$last_names = '';
$s = explode(',', $str1);
foreach($s as $v) {
  $n[] = explode(' ',$v);
}
foreach($n as $ln) {
  $last_names .= end($ln);
}
echo $last_names; //EvansEbinNirenbergFrance
```

and with `preg_match()`

```
$str = 'Evans, C. J. and Ebin, Kupper and Nirenberg, Jhon France';
preg_match_all('/([A-Z])\w+(?=,)/', $str, $matches);
echo implode('',$matches[0]); //EvansEbinNirenberg
```

Comment: The authors are jointed by `and`, thus the last author is `Nirenberg, Jhon France`, and the last name of it is `Nirenberg`

Comment: Thanks for your optional answer!